# Publisher field in Book Review when the book is obtained for free from the internet

Tags: style, publishing, reviews

I'm writing a book review as part of my English Holiday Homework. The book (or rather, prolegomenon) that I'm reviewing is *Battle of the Books* by *Jonathan Swift*.

Due to obvious reasons for my inability to obtain a hard-copy of the book, I defaulted to getting a copy from the internet. I got a couple of sources, including a couple on WikiSource and [this PDF](http://pinkmonkey.com/dl/library1/digi482.pdf).

My question is, what should I put in the 'publisher' field in my book review ( we have to stick to a strict template :/ ):-

- "WikiSource" and a link?
- Google for a publisher that once published the book (though it's books aren't the book I'm using)?
- "N/A"?

**Edit:** I've added an answer on what I think should be put in the field ("WikiSource"). But if anyone can provide reasons for another answer, please add that too :)

Comment: I'm not sure if the reason that I haven't gotten the answer yet is b'coz this site simple isn't as popular as [SO] or b'coz my question is inappropriate or uninteresting in its current form...

Comment: YatharthROCK, welcome to Writers!  This site is *much* smaller than Stack Overflow.  I expect you'll get an answer, but we have fewer users and things take a little longer here.  While you're waiting I hope you'll browse some of our other questions.

Comment: The book was clearly self published, so why don't you use the writer's name on publisher? And, btw, why are you bothering so much with that if the author himself didn't bothered to add his name in the manuscript? I wouldn't spend too much time on ti and use "Jonathan Swift self published".

Comment: @Psicofrenia I think you've got it. Make that an answer.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum It is not really "self" published since the material is being published by others (being in the public domain, originally published along with *A Tale of a Tub* in 1704).

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton I was just going to say that. The author didn't put it up for free, the works were documented by the WikiSource Project after they came into the public domain (possibly from an earlier printed book). I don't think that's self-publishing. I'm more inclined towards "WikiSource"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author didn't put it up for free; the works were documented by the WikiSource Project after they came into the public domain (possibly from an earlier printed book).

I don't think that's self-publishing. From [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/publishing), the definition of a publisher is ‘a person or company whose business is the publishing of books, periodicals, engravings, computer software, etc.’. Sounds like "WikiSource" is the right answer here...

Comment: BTW, this is just what I think. The Q is still open for discussion...